# Add trailing "0" to have each part of the list have 5 chracters

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, infinite-loop

I am trying to iterate over a list (called lista) in order to print out a new list with each part of it having exactly 5 characters.

```
lista = ['123', '2', '34322', '332']


while True:
        for i in lista:
            if len(lista[lista.index(i)]) < 5:
                lista[lista.index(i)] += '0'
        else:
            break
print(lista)
```

My output however, is:

```
['1230', '20', '34322', '3320']
```

The only way I can get the right number of characters is when I create an infinite loop by removing the "break" statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe `i` is what you should be checking the length of, in addition to a few other problems.

Comment: try this, ```[x.rjust( 5, "0") for x in ['123', '2', '34322', '332']]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the output to be in the form of:
['00123', '00002', '34322', '00332']
If this is true, then the below piece of code is your solution!

```
lista = ['123', '2', '34322', '332']
zero="0"
finalList=[]
for i in lista:
    remainingChar=0
    if(len(i)<5):
        remainingChar=5-len(i)
        finalList.append((remainingChar*zero)+i)
    else:
        finalList.append(i)
print(finalList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use built in `zfill`:

```
lista = [x.zfill(5) for x in lista]
```

output:

```
['00123', '00002', '34322', '00332']
```

Comment: Asking for trailing, should be `x.ljust(5, '0')`

Comment: Since the list are digit characters, I assumed OP wants left fill. If OP needs right fill, your answer is the correct one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Single addition of `'0'` happens because of the `if` loop inside the while loop. This can be fixed by adding a `while` loop inside. The first code snippet assumes that the `'0'` should be inserted to the left. The second one inserts the `'0'` to the right.

```
lista = ['123', '2', '34322', '332']


while True:
    for i,j in enumerate(lista):
        while len(lista[i]) < 5:
            lista[i] = '0' + lista[i]
    else:
        break
print(lista)
```

Insertion of `'0'` to the right:

```
lista = ['123', '2', '34322', '332']


while True:
    for i,j in enumerate(lista):
        while len(lista[i]) < 5:
            lista[i] += '0'
    else:
        break
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont use Python, so forgive me if my answer isn't the best in python terms, but I can see from your code that it is behaving exactly as expected.
You need to add another sub loop. So rather than  the 'if' you should add a
while len... add a zero.. sort of thing.
I guess python doesn't have any string.pad functions then. If it does you could use that.
Ah just did a quick search and found this...

[Python site](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-pad-strings-with-zero-space-or-some-other-character/)